# How to get whole part of decimal number in AngularJS bindings

Tags: angularjs, angular-filters

I want to take the whole part of decimal in the price of book. But when I use `Price | number:0` AngularJS rounds the whole part. For instance, if the price is `45.89` it prints the price in browser `46`. So, how to make it print just `45` ?

```
<li class="book-price">{{Price | number:0 }}
    <sup style="font-size: 55%;">
        {{ !((Price*100)%100) ? "00" : (Price*100)%100}}
    </sup>&#8380;
</li>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you provide `number` filter with 0 `fractionSize` Angular will round to nearest whole number. You can create your own filter as [answered by R.J](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39248506/5555803).

OR You can do a math trick. If you subtract `0.5` from your number, Angular will have as you want:

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app>
{{45.89 | number: 0}}<br>
{{45.03 | number: 0}}<br>
{{45.89 - 0.5 | number: 0}}<br>
{{45.03 - 0.5 | number: 0}}<br>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create your own custom [angular#Filter](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/filter)

```
{{45.89 |floorFilter}} //it print 45
```

JS;

```
.filter('floorFilter', function() {

    return function(value) {

      return Math.floor(value);
    }
  })
```

Here is the working [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/fVv6DvWiutmxYQ75pXoQ?p=preview)

EDIT :

If you dont want to create custom filter then

in controller simply do

```
$scope.Price = Math.floor(Price )
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But I don't want to create custom filter.

Comment: @emiraslan Please see EDIT

Comment: @R.J For EDIT. As @emiraslan posted in his question. He uses decimal part of Price in `<sup/>` tag